# R Shiny DT::renderDataTable ...how to customize title in downloaded table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am using following code for datatable...

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(data = filtered_data3(), extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(pageLength = 50,
                        dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = c('copy', 'csv','excel', 'pdf', 'print')),
               rownames = FALSE)
  })

when I am downloading the table I'm getting "plotly-logomark" in title. How can I get rid of that and get desired title on the downloaded table.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
datatable(
  filtered_data3(),
  extensions = 'Buttons',
  options = list(
    pageLength = 50,
    dom = 'Blfrtip',
    buttons = list(
      list(extend = 'copy', title = "My custom title"), 
      list(extend = 'csv', title = "My custom title"), 
      list(extend = 'excel', title = "My custom title"), 
      list(extend = 'pdf', title = "My custom title"), 
      list(extend = 'print', title = "My custom title") 
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Is there any way to get all the drop down selections on downloadable table?

Comment: @user8902946 I don't understand your question. Could you clarify?  Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it worked.

Comment: when we subset data based on ui selections, can we get those selections on table. It will help others to know what options were selected to get the table.